# How to mock GraphServiceClient Microsoft Graph SDK v5

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-graph-api

I want to unit test the following method

```
public async Task<List<VirtualEventWebinar>> GetMany(string title)
{
    var result = await _client.Solutions.VirtualEvents.Webinars.GetAsync();
    return result?.Value != null
        ? result.Value.Where(x => x.DisplayName.Contains(title)).ToList()
        : [];
}
```

> Graph API:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/virtualeventregistration-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp

How would I set it up using Moq?
Is there an interface that I can use for this purpose?

Comment: is `_client` an interface?  If so, just mock that, and then mock Solutions, VirtualEvents.Webinars (with .SetupGet), and finally Mock GetAsync

Comment: client is GraphServiceClient

Answer (score 0):

There is some discussion in GitHub SDK [repo](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/2134). In general, you need to mock either authentication provider or request adapter. The whole setup seems to me too complicated.

I've ended up with a solution where I have `IXXXService` and it's implementation. In the implementation, I'm using `GraphServiceClient` and mocking only the interface.

```
public interface IWebinarService
{
    Task<List<VirtualEventWebinar>> GetAsync();
}

public class WebinarService : IWebinarService
{
    private readonly GraphServiceClient _client;
    public WebinarService(GraphServiceClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }

    public async Task<List<VirtualEventWebinar>> GetAsync()
    {
        var result = await _client.Solutions.VirtualEvents.Webinars.GetAsync();
        return result.Value;
    }
}
```

In your class

```
public async Task<List<VirtualEventWebinar>> GetMany(string title)
{
    // real implementation or mock of IWebinarService
    var result = await _webinarService.GetAsync();
    return result != null
        ? result.Where(x => x.DisplayName.Contains(title)).ToList()
        : [];
}
```